# Scheme:function assistance

Tags: scheme

i am fairly new to Scheme and,i was thinking of a way to cube every number in a given list recursively so far this is what i have:

```
(define (cube-it-list lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (cons (cube-it (first lst)) 
                    (cube-it-list (rest lst)))]))
```

but every time I execute the program i get an error and i'm not sure why that is can anyone help or come up with a better more efficient way to do this.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? post it as part of the question

Answer (score 2):

The function looks fine, maybe the problem is in the `cube-it` procedure or in the way you're calling it. For example, this works:

```
(define (cube-it x)
  (* x x x))

(define (cube-it-list lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)
     empty]
    [else
     (cons (cube-it (first lst))
           (cube-it-list (rest lst)))]))

(cube-it-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 8 27 64 125)
```

As for a "better more efficient way to do this", stick to @svk's answer and [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) over the input list, it's the idiomatic way to solve this type of problem that involves applying a function to each of the elements in an input list, to produce an output list with the results:

```
(map cube-it '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 8 27 64 125)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the function cube-it? When I did, your code worked for me.

In any case, there is a construct in Scheme for precisely this sort of thing: making one list out of another by applying a transformation to each element. It's called map:

```
(map cube-it '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 8 27 64 125)
```

You've essentially reinvented it here, except map is not limited to a single transformation operation - you pass it the function you want to use as its first argument.

(Note, if you've been specifically told to implement a *recursive* solution, you should stick with your original code. map will use recursion internally, but using map means your own code doesn't need to involve any recursion for this case.)