# Scheme functions and lists, multiply,add

Tags: scheme

i am trying to write 2 functions in scheme, the first would multiply every value in a list by a user specified value, 2nd function would add a number to all the values in the list from previous result.
i tried something like that but racket throws an error.

```
(define test (list 1 1 2 3 5))
(define funca(*(test)(2)))
```

Comment: Excessive parens.. Any Scheme implementation will try to call `test` and `2` as if it were procedures.

Comment: As @Sylwester says, _beware of the parentheses_! in Scheme, when you surround something with `()`, it'll be interpreted as a function application. These will rise an error: `(test)`, `(2)` - because `test` and `2` are not functions...

Comment: Please add the error you get in the post. Also, this is almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649352/schemefunction-assistance/15649698#15649698

Answer (score 3):

In Scheme we use the [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) higher-order procedure for applying a function over a list of elements - bear in mind that you can't *multiply* a list, what we *can* do is multiply *each of its elements* . For example, to multiply each of the elements by two do this:

```
(define test (list 1 1 2 3 5))

(map (lambda (element) (* 2 element))
     test)
=> '(2 2 4 6 10)
```

Notice how we pass a `lambda` as parameter to `map`: that's a function that will get applied to each of the elements in the input list, returning a new list with the results. Similarly if we need to, say, add one to the elements in a list:

```
(map (lambda (element) (+ 1 element))
     test)

=> '(2 2 3 4 6)
```

The above examples are hard-coded to multiply by two and to add one. For solving your problem, you just have to put each of the above snippets inside a function and pass along the correct parameters in the right places (left as an exercise for the reader).