# Scheme operation on a function

Tags: scheme

Is it possible to do an operation on a previous function, i have a list of values say (1,2,3,4,5), first function needs to multiply them by 2, while 2nd function adds 1 to result of previous function, so first we would get (2,4,6,8,10), and then (3,5,7,9,11) i got this, function g does extra work, is it possible nstead of doing operations on the element do it on function F or results from function F

```
#lang racket
(define test (list 1 1 2 3 5))

(define (F)
  (map (lambda (element) (* 2 element))
       test))

(define (G)
  (map (lambda (element) (+ 1 (* 2 element)))
       test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to correctly define your procedures to take a list parameter (called `lst` in this case):

```
(define (F lst)
  (map (lambda (e) (* 2 e)) lst))

(define (G lst)
  (map add1 lst))
```

Then

```
> (F '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(2 4 6 8 10)
> (G '(2 4 6 8 10))
'(3 5 7 9 11)
```

or, if you need to combine both procedures:

```
> (G (F '(1 2 3 4 5)))
'(3 5 7 9 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow-up to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25729505/201359). As stated in my answer there, you should pass the right *parameters* to the functions - in particular, pass the input lists as parameter, so you can use the result from one function as input for the next function:

```
(define test (list 1 1 2 3 5))

(define (multiply-list test)
  (map (lambda (element) (* 2 element))
       test))

(define (add-list test)
  (map (lambda (element) (+ 1 element))
       test))
```

Now, if we want to add one to each element in the input list:

```
(add-list test)
=> '(3 3 5 7 11)
```

Or if we want to multiply by two each element in the input list:

```
(multiply-list test)
=> '(2 2 4 6 10)
```

And if we want to add one first, then multiply by two we can chain the functions! the result from one becomes the input for the other, and the final result will be as follows:

```
(multiply-list (add-list test))
=> '(6 6 10 14 22)
```

Answer (score 0):

*NB! You have tagged scheme but you use racket (the language). Not all of my examples will work in scheme.*

Yes! you even do it yourself in your definition of `G` where you add a value and the result of a multiplication.

Its possible to chain map

```
(map f3 (map f2 (map f1 lst)))
```

Thus if you instead make a function that takes a list and doubles it:

```
(define (list-double lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) lst))
```

You can chain it to quadruple it:

```
(define (list-quadruple lst)
  (list-double (list-double lst)))
```

Now it's not optimal to chain map if you can avoid it. Instead you can compose the procedures together:

```
(define (double x) (* x 2))
(define (list-quadrouple lst)
  (map (compose1 double double) lst))
```

`compose1` here is the same as making a anonymous function where you chain the arguments. Eg. the last would be `(lambda (x) (double (double x)))`. A more complex one `compose` can do more than one value between procedures. eg. `(compose + quotient/remainder)`